# Manipulaitng javascript cookie on blur , focus ,onload and tabclose?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I will try to be as clear as possible.

Ok.I am making a simple tracker where it becomes very important for me to track user behaviour .I am using a javascript cookie for this purpose.

**what I do** :

1. After tracking the user,I get some data which I store in a javascript object literal.

   ```
   var object = {
     home-page :0-30,
     brand-page:0-90,
     mark-page :0-20,
     home-page :0-10
   }
   ```
2. I `JSON.stringify` the object to store the object value in a cookie.

**MyQuestion** :

1. Considering that there are two tabs opened and that I write some data in my cookie on second tab...would I get that latest data on `window.focus` of first tab if i read the same cookie?
2. Now when I come on the first tab,I want to update a property of my object(for example..home-page:0-30 is to be updated ),without altering
   its order and updating the wrong property.

Can anybody guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you json is incorrect, it should contain only one unique id

```
var object = {'home-page' :'0-30', 'brand-page': '0-90', 'mark-page' : '0-20'}
```

Answer to you first question, yes you will get the updated data from second tab if both the tab have same domain.

Second Question: Yes you can update the same cookie and update the user info in same cookie.

You can check the steps at http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/fhe27/2/